# In what sense is a constant sheaf of abelian groups with stalks G isomorphic to G?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

In the English translation of Serre's FAC (link to the PDF can be found in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14404/serres-fac-in-english) mathoverflow discussion in the top answer) Serre gives his first example of a sheaf of abelian groups, the constant sheaf, on page 8 in section 1: Operations on Sheaves. The following is verbatim from the translation, however do note that Serre defines a sheaf from the étalé space point of view, the definition is also given on page 8 or can be found online.

> **Example** of a sheaf. For $G$ an abelian group, set $\mathscr{F}_x = G$ for all $x \in X$; the set $\mathscr{F}$ can be identified with the product $X \times G$ and, if it is equipped with the product topology of the topology of $X$ by the discrete topology on G, one obtains a sheaf, called the *constant sheaf* isomorphic with $G$, and often identified with $G$.

For the most part I understand this example. I am able to verify that the group operation maps are continuous, and the projection map is a local homeomorphism, so $\mathscr{F}$ is indeed a sheaf using the definition that Serre gives. Then for the sake of exploration I studied the sections of this sheaf and found that $\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})$ is the group of locally constant functions $s\colon U \to \mathscr{F}$. Further, if $U$ is connected they become constant functions and then $\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F}) \cong G$, but if not connected $\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F}) \cong \oplus \, G$ where you get a summand for each connected component of $U$. None of this stuff is too exciting, and can be found on the wikipedia page for the constant sheaf. But what I **do not get** is

> In what sense would this constant sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ be *isomorphic* to $G$? Why would we want to *identify* it with $G$? I see no way that the **sheaf itself** acts like $G$, and really it is more like no matter where you look on this sheaf (stalks, sections) you are either going to find $G$, or find copies of $G$. I checked the french version and it is not a translation error. Can anyone provide some context or explanation for this?

Here is another example of where Serre uses this language in a way that is confusing to me:

> Every sheaf of abelian groups can be considered a sheaf of
>   $\mathbb{Z}$ - modules, $\mathbb{Z}$ being the constant sheaf
>   isomorphic to the ring of integers.

Also, here is another (less important) question that occurred to me while typing my original question up that I don't think is quite worthy of its own post (but I'll move it if someone complains):

> Does anything weird happen when the subset $U$ has countably many or
>   uncountably many connected components? Usually we would want to switch
>   to a direct product of $G$ but that seems not to be what we would want, since we wouldn't want to require the sections to be nontrivial on only finitely many components?

Comment: Is "isomorphic to $G$" an assertion about this particular sheaf? It's been a while, and I don't have my copy of Hartshorne with me, but I would read "isomorphic to $G$" as part of the name of the sheaf: it's "constant", and the value it always "takes" is $G$. If $X$ is understood from context, we can just say "$G$", i.e., use "$G$" to "identify" it. (Guesswork, mind you; I'd want to see how Hartshorne says it, since I learned the stuff from him)

Comment: I believe Hartshorne defines the constant sheaf to be the sheaffification of the constant presheaf

Comment: I was wrong, he has an exercise where you show that the sheaffification of the constant presheaf is the constant sheaf, but he defines the constant sheaf by giving $G$ the discrete topology and then the functor $F$ takes $U$ to the set of continuous functions $s: U \to G$ and he also remarks that $F(U) \cong G$ for each connected $U$.

Comment: My point is really about nomenclature. On first reading, I would interpret the paragraph as saying that the name of the sheaf is "constant sheaf isomorphic with $G$", rather than saying the sheaf's name is "Constant sheaf" followed by an assertion that it is isomorphic to $G$; you seem to be reading the latter, though, so I would want to see what others call it.

Comment: He doesn't say anything about being isomorphic to $G$, maybe I am just overthinking it and Serre just means "if $G$ is an abelian group but I start saying 'the sheaf $G$' I mean the constant sheaf with stalks $G$" ... which is basically what you were saying above.